# Android Permissions accessible by rooting the device?

Tags: android, root

We are trying to weight the choice to either root or not the devices to run a very specific App.

What we want to know if permissions like WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS, WRITE_APN_SETTINGS and the like that were usable on past versions of Android are available if we root our devices.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get straight to the point and answer your question, yes, it is.

Comment: Really! Do you have an example of how to do it? I will start searching. Thanks

Comment: Yes. It will work up to 4.3 (unfortunately Android 4.4 has added security) if,



-Manifest has WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS

-App is in /system/app/

-The package is signed by a key (any key)

Comment: I am seeing the requirements. I am currently reading how to sign the app.
Thanks for your answer.

Comment: No problem! Glad to help. Best of luck to you.